# Unit Testing Fragment has caused code inflation

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-fragments

Upon implementing unit testing on my `Fragment`, I have doubled the length of code in my class. Are there certain best practices I should follow, or am I over-testing? Should this all be an implementation test instead?

Of particular note is the method `connectToBehaviorRelay(behaviorRelay, artistResultFunction, getConsumer(), mySchedulerProvider);`. I could remove some of these parameters but I would then have to create further `@VisibleForTesting` methods.

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ArtistReleasesActivity.component.inject(this);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recyclerview, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        connectToBehaviorRelay(behaviorRelay, artistResultFunction, getConsumer(), mySchedulerProvider);
        setupRecyclerView(getActivity());
        return view;
    }

    @VisibleForTesting(otherwise = VisibleForTesting.PRIVATE)
    public void connectToBehaviorRelay(BehaviorRelay<List<ArtistRelease>> behaviorRelay, ArtistResultFunction artistResultFunction, Consumer<List<ArtistRelease>> consumer, SchedulerProvider mySchedulerProvider)
    {
        behaviorRelay
                .map(artistResultFunction.map(getArguments().getString("map")))
                .observeOn(mySchedulerProvider.ui())
                .subscribe(consumer);
    }

    private Consumer<List<ArtistRelease>> getConsumer()
    {
        return o ->
        {
            rvReleasesAdapter.setRemixes(o);
            rvReleasesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        };
    }

    @VisibleForTesting(otherwise = VisibleForTesting.PRIVATE)
    public void setupRecyclerView(FragmentActivity activity)
    {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity));
        rvReleasesAdapter = new RecyclerViewReleasesAdapter(activity);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(rvReleasesAdapter);
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    public void setArtistResultFunction(ArtistResultFunction artistResultFunction)
    {
        this.artistResultFunction = artistResultFunction;
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    public void setRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView)
    {
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
    }
```

My question is: do I need to have all these lines or should I move some to a `Presenter`? Having them within a `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` seems to complicate things.

Comment: `@VisibleForTesting` annotation is good signal that you have problems with architecture.

Comment: @azizbekian Thought so. Could I just move the majority of this logic to a `Presenter` and just use integration tests for this `Fragment`?

Comment: Theoretically - yes. Practically - depends how coupled is your code now.